# Using Selenium with Python: Error when using select boxes on IE9

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, click

When I'm filling out a form in IE9, selecting an option from a dropbox often causes the following error:

```
"the xpath expression '//...' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement"
```

This error does not occur in firefox, but only in IE.
Does anyone know a way around this issue?  The only *possible* solution (wasn't checked as correct) I saw was written in Java.  Using find_element_by_id(id) still works fine; of course, that is meaningless if there is no id.  Here's an example of when the error often occurs:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='name']/option[text()='option1']").click()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Select()` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) that provides a nice abstraction over select/option structures:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('name'))
select.select_by_visible_text('option1')
```

Comment: awesome! that works for the select boxes :D  Odd that I haven't even seen that anywhere, though....... I should've put this into 2 separate questions, because I want to give a best answer for both issues hehe I'm going to wait to see if someone knows what to do for the expand boxes, first, though

Comment: @user2869231 what if you would edit the question and move the "expand boxes" part to a separate question? Would make sense I think. Thanks.